# Assign a method to a var?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vueuse

I set an event listener when my nav is shown in `show`, this is via `onClickOutside` from `VueUse`.

I assign the returned method from `onClickOutside` to a var, calling this later turns off the event listener.

My question is, how can I assign the click handler in `show` and unassign in `hide`?

Do I need to set the `unsubscribe` var somewhere else?

```
async function show() {
    active.value = true;
    unsubscribe = onClickOutside(menu, () => {
        if (active.value) {
            hide();
        }
    });

    await nextTick();
    activate();
}

function hide() {
    unsubscribe();
    active.value = false;
    deactivate();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Examining the [source code](https://github.com/vueuse/vueuse/blob/main/packages/core/onClickOutside/index.ts) there is a `cleanup` array in the `onClickOutside` composable. A function called `stop` runs on each element of the array and stops the events. This is returned by the system when the student is created. So to stop you simply call the function.

It is clear from the source code that the return type of the `stop` function is `void`, that is, it returns nothing. Therefore, the `unsubscribe` variable remains an option to call the `stop` function again, which is now meaningless.

You didn't share the full source code, so if it's within the scope of a function, it's understandable. However, if `unsubscribe` is a variable that exists for the lifetime of the application, I'd set it back to `undefined` for clarity.

And this way, if `unsubscribe` is not `undefined`, I wouldn't redeclare the `onClickOutside` call to avoid duplicates.

```js
let unsubscribe;

async function show() {
    active.value = true;

    // avoid duplicated invocation by using ??= (so if it's not undefined, the variable assignment won't be overwritten)
    unsubscribe ??= onClickOutside(menu, () => {
        if (active.value) {
            hide();
        }
    });

    await nextTick();
    activate();
}

function hide() {
    if (unsubscribe) unsubscribe();

    // set it to undefined so that we know next time that it no longer exists
    unsubscribe = undefined;

    active.value = false;
    deactivate();
}
```